# How can construct the equilateral $A''B''C''$ such that area of $A''B''C''$ is biggest

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, polygons

Let $ABC$ be arbitrary triangle in a plane. Let $A'B'C'$ and $A''B''C''$ be two equilateral triangles such that $A \in B'C'$, $B \in C'A'$, $C \in A'B'$ and $A \in B''C''$, $B \in C''A''$, $C \in A''B''$

1. How can construct the equilateral $A'B'C'$ such that $AA'$, $BB'$, $CC'$ are concurrent;
2. How can construct the equilateral $A''B''C''$ such that area of $A''B''C''$ is biggest;

**See also:**

- [Malfatti circles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malfatti_circles)
- [Cramer–Castillon problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%E2%80%93Castillon_problem)

[image]